# External javascript writes in latin-1

Tags: javascript, encoding

I'm a bit stuck, given my page includes an external JavaScript which uses `document.write`. The problem is my page is UTF-8 encoded, and the contents written are encoded in latin-1, which causes some display problems.

Is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE?  In other words, how are you declaring your page to be UTF-8?

Comment: there is no meta tag that defines the page encoding, but firefox tells me the page is UTF8 encoded... when I switch to ISO-8859-1, the weird characters from the footer (generated by the external javascript) disappear...

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit never having had to mix encodings, but in theory you should be able to specify the `charset` attribute ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-charset)) on the `script` tag — but be sure you're not conflicting with it when serving the external file. From that link:

> The `charset` attribute gives the character encoding of the external script resource...its value must be a valid character encoding name, must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for the preferred MIME name for that encoding, and must match the encoding given in the `charset` parameter of the Content-Type metadata of the external file, if any.

So that will tell the browser how to interpret the script data, provided your server provides the same `charset` (or doesn't supply any `charset`) in the `Content-Type` header when serving up the script file.

Once the browser is reading the script with the right charset, you should be okay, because by the time JavaScript is dealing with strings, they're UTF-16 (according to Section 8.4 of [the 5th edition spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)).

Comment: I'm not sure that works everywhere; Chrome for example seems to pay attention only to an encoding declaration in a `<meta>` tag in the head, or (maybe) in the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @Pointy: The `<meta>` tag on the HTML document will control what the charset is for the document. Chrome *should* respect the `charset` of the external script resource. But as I say, I've never actually had to mix charsets like this, just quoting what the specs tell us. :-) The real world may well vary. (I'm actually itching to try it now, but I just don't have time today.)

Comment: Yes I'm not very sure on this either. I'd actually prefer that `document.write` didn't exist at all, for this and many other reasons.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah. :-) Although again, by the time the `document.write` executes, it's dealing with a UTF-16 string. This `charset` stuff is all about how the script gets *read* -- the actual characters in the JavaScript file itself... But I'm with you on `document.write` regardless.

Comment: @Rolf: Sounds like some progress, anyway. Re IE: You're being careful about the `Content-Type` header being returned with the script file? Your server isn't contradicting you?